# Getting origin and time of last Pasteboard item entry on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, unix, nspasteboard, pasteboard

Is there any way I can get the last time of entry made to the NSPasteboard and the application from which the copy/cut operation was performed on a Mac using Objective-C code or some terminal command